# How to make a label's width take a percentage of a window in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Currently, I have been trying to create a label so that it fills about 25 percent of the screen but I cannot seem to figure out how to do so given that the width seems to work differently in comparison to the window's resolution.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

# App Title
root.title("YouTube Video Downloader")

# Screen Resolution
custom_width = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
custom_height = int(root.winfo_screenheight() / 2)
screen_resolution = str(custom_width) + "x" + str(custom_height)
root.geometry(screen_resolution)
root.update()

# Side Taskbar
side_taskbar = tk.Label(
    root,
    background="#262730",
    width=int(root.winfo_reqwidth() / 4),
    height=custom_height
)
side_taskbar.pack()
side_taskbar.place(x=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is how it looks. It may look like it's getting 25% but it is slightly off.

[Code being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sscvk.png)

Comment: Are you displaying just a single label on the entire window, or are there other widgets. The way you would do this for a single widget probably isn't the way you would do it if you had a more complicated GUI.

Comment: Yeah, I am just gonna change the background color of the window that I didn't include in the code there and just have the label take about 25% percent of the window in terms of width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
side_taskbar = tk.Label(
    root, text='25%',
    bg="black",fg='white'     
)
```

To select wide and height.

```
side_taskbar = tk.Label(
    root, text='Percentage',
    background="#262730",fg='white',
    width=8,
    height=4
)
```